# How to send the log output of ASP.NET Core 5.0 website to the frontend

Tags: .net, logging, log4net, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 5.0 web application which is some kind of an administration tool. In the background the application makes heavy use of the frameworks [logging functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging).

However now I would like to send the log stream with signalR to the frontend. The signalR part is working fine. But I have no clue how I can get the logging stream into one of my controllers. Is there a [build-in logging provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging-providers) which can be used for this job? Or is there a way to create a custom logging provider?

I would really appreciate your proposals.

Comment: [Implement a custom logging provider in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider)

Comment: I think the solution proposed by Guru Stron has the limitation that if you have multiple servers only the logs of the server you connect to will be streamed. Clearly the client could connect to all the servers separately. The other big problem is that the solution solves the "real time" problem: you can see logs that are being written NOW. But if you open the page NOW, how can you see logs from 1h before?

Comment: Another simple solution: you log to the DB, with a timestamp (in sql timestamps are numbers that always increase). Every x seconds the client asks the server for all the messages > last known timestamp

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes indeed I will need historical data. Therefore I guess I will go the way with the database as log cache.